# How to use trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I'm using the `AdventureWorks2012` database. I created a stored procedure to update the product with a new name in `Production.Product` table for a given product id only if cost of product cost is greater than 100

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_PRODUCTRENAME
    (@NAME NVARCHAR(50), 
     @PRODUCTID INT, 
     @STANDARDCOST NUMERIC) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE Production.Product 
    SET Name = @NAME 
    WHERE ProductID = 515 AND StandardCost >= 100; 
END;
```

Here even if I am passing cost < 100 the product name is getting changed.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Why do you want to do this in a `TRIGGER` in the first place? Triggers activate on a DML events, they can't be parametrised. What are you actually trying the achieve here? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What are you really asking?

Comment: Basically, whenever I UPDATE the product name in the table, there should be a trigger to  show that name has been updated or not based on the condition

Comment: What do you mean "show"?

Comment: Like store an event in a table with details like datestamp when the name was updated or simply print in the message into results after executing the query

Comment: Personally, if you want to log information like that, I would still suggest it goes in the Procedure, not in a trigger.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your valuable input. Also in the above code of Procedure, even if the condition is not satisfied like cost is < 100, the name is getting updated. What am i doing wrong there ?

Comment: Why are you passing in parameters `@ProductId` and `@StandardCost`, but then using **fixed** values in your procedure? Shouldn't you be using these parameters ??

Comment: @marc_s because, i am new to SQL server and i  am learning and this is what i could write on my own seeing some tutorials. Hence requesting help with correct syntax/code

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROD_PRODUCT_RENAME(@NAME NVARCHAR(50), @PRODUCTID INT, @STANDARDCOST NUMERIC)
AS
IF @STANDARDCOST <=100
BEGIN
RAISERROR(' Cannot Update Product Name as cost should be greater than 100',16,1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE Production.Product
SET Name = @NAME
WHERE ProductID = @PRODUCTID
AND StandardCost > @STANDARDCOST;
END;
```

This is what I came up with. Hope is the correct answer